# How to make default role array dynamic in Fuse React's role authorization system?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We are using Fuse React template in our project. In this template the routes are generated from config files of single routes. When the generation occurs a default role array is embedded to every route. This means that if /dashboard route has a role array like ['admin','staff'] and if the user role is 'user' than this user is not granted access to /dashboard. This route generation is occuring when app first loaded.

this is where generated routes are used. its imported from the config file below.

```
console.log('routes: ', routes);
const App = () => {
    return (
        <AppContext.Provider
            value={{
                routes
            }}>
            <StylesProvider jss={jss} generateClassName={generateClassName}>
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <Auth>
                        <Router history={history}>
                            <FuseAuthorization>
                                <FuseTheme>
                                    <FuseLayout />
                                </FuseTheme>
                            </FuseAuthorization>
                        </Router>
                    </Auth>
                </Provider>
            </StylesProvider>
        </AppContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default App;
```

And this is the main config file where all the routes get their auth property embedded in.

```
const defaultAuth = ['superadmin', 'admin', 'staff', 'user'];

const routes = [
     ...FuseUtils.generateRoutesFromConfigs(routeConfigs, defaultAuth), //This method embeds
    {
        path: '/',
        exact: true,
        auth: '',
        component: () => <Redirect to="/login" />
    },
    {
        path: '/dashboard',
        exact: true,
        auth: '',
        component: () => <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
    },
    {
        component: () => <Redirect to="/pages/errors/error-404" />
    }
];

export default routes;
```

Problem: When the user logs in I get an Id from token. Then using this Id I get the arrays which shows me which routes granted access to which roles. The problem is that this routes are generated before user logs in and so I cant get an Id. I need to get the user login before route generation and using his/her Id to get role array and generate the routes based on that array. Any ideas how can I achieve this?

What did I try: I tried to move AppContext.Provider to lower levels and it didn't work of course. I expected to generate routes after authorization but since login component doesn't generated it didn't open at all.

Answer (score 0):

I used another approach and disregarded this thought. Instead of using default array when user logs in I get my own arrays from database and use them for role check. In future if someone needs help I can explain details.